# How to check if all values of an array are equal to each other?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to check if an array has all the same value in it. An example would be as follows.

```
array1 = np.array([1,1,1,1,1]) would return True
array2 = np.array([1,0,1,0,1]) would return False
```

I know how to check if all values in an array are equal to a certain value. But I want to check if all values in the array are equal to each other, no matter what the value is. Is there a way to do this with just Numpy without creating a function?

Comment: If you know how to check if all values are a certain value, use that same method but use `array[0]` as the value to check.

Comment: The issue with that is it returns an array of True and False. I need only True or False.

Comment: Then it's not really checking if *all* values are equal to a certain value.

Answer (score 5):

You can use python sets. If the length of the set is 1, all values are the same:

```
>>> len(set(array1)) == 1
True

>>> len(set(array2)) == 1
False
```

Answer (score 4):

This works too and seems to be slightly faster than some other approaches:

```
>>> array1 = np.array([1,1,1,1,1])
>>> array2 = np.array([1,0,1,0,1])
>>> (array1 == array1[0]).all()
True
>>> (array2 == array2[0]).all()
False
```

Some **very** coarse timing figures for a 10k array, compared to other solutions:

- this approach: 1.07 msec
- `np.isin()`: 1.23 msec
- `set()`: 2.63 msec

Comment: I confirm that it's the fastest at the time of this comment. Nice!

Answer (score 3):

This can be used-
[np.unique](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html)

```
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([1,1,1,1,1])
#following passes assertion test
assert(len(np.unique(array1, return_counts=True)[0])==1)

#without getting counts of unique values
#assert(len(np.unique(array1))==1)

array2 = np.array([1,0,1,0,1])
#following will throw an assertion error
assert(len(np.unique(array2, return_counts=True)[0])==1)
```

Comment: I need it to return True or False, not an assertion error.

Comment: @Conweezy Replace `assert()` with `print()`

Answer (score 2):

My attempt would be to compare all items to the first item and then check if the result contains a `False`:

```
import numpy as np
array1 = np.array([1,1,1,1,1])
print(not np.isin(False, array1 == array1[0]))
```

On my machine, this becomes faster than the `len(set())` version at about 700 numbers in the array. At 10000 items, it's faster by a factor of 5.5. But it's slower than the `np.unique()` version.
<sub>Measured on a Core i7-10750H, 10000 iterations</sub>